# I cant open the file <Projectname>/res/layout while working with android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, perspective

I have simply been trying to reset the eclipse perspective for working with android and have found it very frustrating. I want to open the file /res/layout activity_android.xml but cannot for some reason. Does anyone know a way around this problem or a way to change the perspective in some way.

Comment: Can you see the folder structure ?

Comment: "but cannot for some reason": can you be a bit more specific here?

Comment: might be u r not in proper view change to java if it is not